# AutoHotKey Mapping For Mouse

Tags: autohotkey

Here is what I am trying to do:

When user clicks mouse, move mouse scroller ( the roller in the middle of the mouse ( I have a Microsoft Intelli-Mouse ) ) by 1 upward. This should go on forever.

Example: user clicks mouse, page moves up.

All I need to know are what is the "mapping", is it called, for click and scroll up 1.

For example: Crt+Alt+s = ^!s, what is MouseClick and MouseScrollUp?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a solution (using the middle button, option to change to `lbutton` or `rbutton`)

```
MButton::
While GetKeyState("MButton", "P")
{
    Send, {WheelUp 1}
}
return
```